# Building a python function that modifies lists with tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, tuples, iterable-unpacking

Hi guys I'm having the current problem:

```
list_a = [('abc d',1), ('abc d',2) ,('acb e',3) ,('b',1),('b',2),('b',3)]
```

from list_a, I am trying to build a function that would return the following output...

Essentially I want to keep all [0] values that start with the string 'a' and make modifications to its respective [1]'s.

The modification being a simple [1] x 2 ...

```
('abc d',1) --> ('abc d',2)
('abc d',2) --> ('abc d',4)
('act d',3) --> ('abc d',6)
```

Keeping the other pairs as they were since they start off with a 'b' in the [0] position.

Desired Output:

```
[('abc d',2), ('abc d',4) ,('acb e',6) ,('b',1),('b',2),('b',3)]
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: What have you tried so far and what specific part are you having trouble with?

Comment: Hi Axe319, thanks for asking. I tried to unpack them first, then zip them again in the right order. But this process would work in other iterative process in the code I am currently. working on :(

Comment: So, multiply `x[1]` by 2 if `x[0]` starts with `a`?

Comment: "make modifications to its respective [1]'s." Do you want to *change* the tuples, or are you fine creating new tuples?

Answer (score 2):

Just use list comprehension

```
list_b = [(i[0],i[1] * 2) if i[0].startswith("a") else i for i in list_a ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the following way.

```
list_a = [('abc d',1), ('abc d',2) ,('acb e',3) ,('b',1),('b',2),('b',3)]

def foo(list_a):
    output=[]
    for x,y in list_a:
        if x[0] =="a":
            output.append((x,2*y))
        else:
            output.append((x,y))
    return output
```

Comment: This doesnt check if the first element starts with an "a"